# 'FIELDNAME' not part of an aggregate function - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to select all `[Operation]`'s from my database and get data about each one. Below is the SQL code I am trying to use.

The following error occurs:

`You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'op' as part of an aggregate function`

My SQL Statement:

```
SELECT [op] as [Operation], Sum(count) as [Number of Breakdowns], Sum(td) as [Sum of Time Down]
FROM
(
  SELECT [Operation] as op, Count(*) as count, Sum([Time Down]) as td
  FROM tblDailyDowntimeAssy
  WHERE [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown'
UNION ALL
  SELECT [Operation] as op, Count(*) as count, Sum([Time Down]) as td
  FROM tblDailyDowntimeMach
  WHERE [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown'
);
```

NOTE:

If I try to use just the `[Operation]` field and don't rename it `op`, the error still occurs but just changes 'op' to 'operation'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT [Operation], Sum(count) as [Number of Breakdowns], Sum(td) as [Sum of Time Down]
FROM
(
  SELECT [Operation], Count(*) as count, Sum([Time Down]) as td
  FROM tblDailyDowntimeAssy
  WHERE [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown'
  group by [Operation]
UNION ALL
  SELECT [Operation], Count(*) as count, Sum([Time Down]) as td
  FROM tblDailyDowntimeMach
  WHERE [Type of Maintenance] = 'Breakdown'
  group by [Operation]
)
group by Operation;
```

You need to add GROUP BY clauses in the queries as you are using aggregate functions.

Comment: Good edit, I was just about to post that you needed to add that for it to be right haha. Thanks a lot, that saved me a lot of time. Why do I need to add the `group by` for this to work correctly?

Comment: You need the `group by` because you are doing an aggregation query where you want multiple rows, one for each `operation`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I understand right - I need the `group by` clause because I am searching through multiple queries (aggregated) and the query needs to know what it combines data together by. In this case, it combines data around my [Operation] field.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a group by clause on your query

```
select ..... from tbl_name
group by ....
```

and then add the field to the group by clause mentioned on the error